# Placing multiple images in HTML at once with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image

**EDIT :** Here's another problem: I can't define each picture's `Z-index` with the for loop.

```
function placeImage(x) {
    var div = document.getElementById("div_picture_right");

    div.innerHTML = ""; // clear images

    for (counter = 1; counter <= x; counter++ ) {
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = "borboleta/Borboleta" + counter + ".png";
        image.width = "195";
        image.height = "390";
        image.alt = "borboleta" + counter;
        image.id = "imagem" + counter;
        image.position = "relative";
        image.style.zIndex = counter;
        div.appendChild(image);
    }
};

window.onload = function () {
    placeImage(20);
};
```

---

```
<body>
    <div id="div_wrapper">
        <div id="div_header">
            <h1>First Project</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="div_picture">
            <div id="div_picture_left"></div>
            <div id="div_picture_right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**When checking FireBug, I get this:**

> Error: image corrupt or truncated

Comment: Do you have a div with an ID of `div_picture_right`? Also check if your code executes before the div exists on the page. Use `window.onload` to prevent that.

Comment: I edited the code like you said. I'll try that.

Comment: place your js at the end of the file else write `defer="defer"` to your `<script>` tag

Comment: @user1925416 see my answer for how to use `window.onload` properly, you aren't using it quite right.

Comment: Yes you cannot pass counter number to the window.onload function @MrCode is right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your code is executing before the `div` exists on the page. You shouldn't try to get a handle on an element in the DOM until it is fully loaded. You can define your function outside of `window.onload`, but keep your call within `window.onload`, example:

```
function placeImage(x)
{
    var div = document.getElementById("div_picture_right");

    div.innerHTML = ""; // clear images

    for (counter=1;counter<=x;counter++) {
        var imagem=document.createElement("img");
        imagem.src="borboleta/Borboleta"+counter+".png";
        div.appendChild(imagem);
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    placeImage(48);
};
```

I also added a small improvement which is to get the handle on the `div` and store in a variable once, instead of getting a new handle on each iteration.

Comment: I would vote your responde Up, but I'm not allowed (must have level 15). It worked!! Thank you so much!

Edit: Nevermind, I voted xD

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var placeImage = function(x) {
var img="";
for (var counter = 1; counter <= x; counter++ ) {
     img += '<img src="borboleta\Borboleta'+counter+'.png" alt="" />';
}
    document.getElementById("div_picture_right").innerHTML = img;
};

placeImage(48);
```

With this code, there's only 1 DOM operation rather than 48.
Also make sure if you have an element with the said ID (div_picture_right).

Comment: Thanks for the effort, you nearly drove me there! Much appreciated!

Comment: Interesting thesis about the DOM operations, but I believe it to be false, since the assigned innerHTML still has to be parsed. According to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9aFS/1/), mass inserting with JavaScript instead of prebuilding html is even faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the divs' z-index dynamically, set their position attribute to "absolute" instead of "relative". It makes more sense that way.